# How to increse number of sitemapindex

Tags: xml, seo, sitemap, googlebot

I'm intereset if i can have many sitemapindex like this:

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
<loc>https://domain.com/sitemap/destinatieTag.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2015-02-01T05:00:34+02:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

I mean 1 sitemapindex to refer athor sitemapindex , or what is maxium limit for a sitemap?

Example if destinatieTag.xml is athor

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
<loc>https://domain.com/sitemap/myUrlXML.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2015-02-01T05:00:34+02:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

and only myUrlXML.xml contain a url xml example:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<url>
<loc>https://domain.com/romania</loc>
</url>
</urlset>
```

I need do a sitemap on my website and have a dinamical link who need do partial permutation for a list of object and for all partial permutation need do athor partial permuation with athor list of object to be clear i can have a url like this if both list cotain only 2 object:

```
/exame/0/0
/exame/0/0;1
/exame/0/1
/example/0;1/0
/example/0;1/0;1
/example/0;1/1
/example/1/0
/example/1/0;1
/example/1/1
```

and this force to have mach url for big number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Google, a sitemap can contain references to other sitemaps, but only with one cascading level. So `sitemapindex` to `destinatieTag.xml` is fine, but `destinatieTag.xml` to `myUrlXML.xml` is not.

There can be up to 50 000 URLs in `sitemapindex` pointing to other sitemaps. Those sitemaps can each contain 50 000 URLs to webpages. All of these sitemaps and URLs must be for the same website.